# Add subviews to PDFView

Tags: ios, swift, pdfview

I need to place some UILabel as subviews of a PDFView, this labels should be placed on specific pages of the PDFView and should scroll with the document.

How can I achieve this? I looked for a reference of scrollview in PDFView class but I don't find it.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a class PDFT and inherit PDFView
override method drawPagePost

```
public class PDFT : PDFView {
     public override func drawPagePost(_ page: PDFPage, to context: CGContext) {
    // add subview in here
    let subview = UIView()
    self.documentView?.addSubview(subview)
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting this `Inheritance from non-protocol type 'PDFView'` error. It is workable previously but not working anymore? Or this is not correct?